# Не вставляется json в базу

Tags: php, postgresql

Привет. Почему-то не вставляется JSON в базу. Сделал `CREATE TABLE searches(id serial PRIMARY KEY, data jsonb NOT NULL);`, после чего создал соединение и пытаюсь положить данные в таблицу:

```
if(isset($_POST['data']) && !empty($_POST['data'])) {
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    //DB
    $db = getdb();
    $query = "INSERT INTO searches (data) VALUES ('$data') RETURNING id";
    $result = pg_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());
    pg_close($db);
    echo $result;
}
```

Но возникает ошибка в строке создания переменной `$query`:

> Notice:  Array to string conversion

Как исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$data = json_encode($_POST['data']);
```